# ID Value Resource: Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent

I am following along the demo on this website to gain a general idea of how Android Studio works.
For the following portion of the code, it says to "press Alt+Enter" to clear errors. The problem is that the editText in line 3 ( R.id.editText ) is making me create a new id value resource or renaming the reference (which I do not want to do).

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can someone explain what the id value resource is? Also, suggestions on how to fix this issue? I am new to Android Studio, so I do not understand what exactly this means.

Thank you.
[it says "error: cannot find symbol"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVAOW.png)

Comment: this is id value resource , R.id.editText , an id that references your view from your activity but about the error , i don't think your code contains any errors , could you show an image of what is showing line three ?

Comment: @takieddine I added an image! Hope it helps

Comment: in your activity main layout , i suppose you have added an edittext , so to solve that issue simply add R.id.editText as an id , if you can't solve it , just copy paste your layout and i will set it for you

Comment: Okay I tried that earlier. The app loads, but when I type something and click the button, the app crashes. Do I need to assign the id a resource value?

Comment: Yeah you need to assign id to your edittext , i suggested you a solution below , check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue , i suppose in your activity main layout you have added an editText as view , this is how to add Editext into your layout

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" //this is the id value
    />
```

In your activity code set the id this way

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" ... /> 

This is what I have in my xml file

Comment: So your editext has this id editTextTextPersonName , in your activity , change R.id.edittext with R.id.editTextTextPersonName and the issue is supposed to be solved

Answer (score 0):

Id of a resource is uniq identifier , such as name of a variable. It should be uniq or you will have problems with names.

Xml file where it write :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--LOOOOOOOOOOOOOK HERE-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/placeHereIdWhichYouWant"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Some text"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your string `editText.getText().toString();` just take text from your `EditText` View. Just give the id for EditText and all will work , if it doesn't import R. to your class

```
package com.example.test //here name of your package

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: For your comment `<EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" ... /> ` change id here to @+id/editText ,             or change `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);` for this `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);`